# The "mind hacks" close reason after the death of Productivity SE

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, moderation, close-reasons

One of the close reasons for this site currently reads:

> **"Mind hacks" are off topic** — Questions dealing with personal productivity and self-improvement tips are a better fit for our **[Personal Productivity site](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/)**. Questions dealing with memorization, learning techniques, etc. are outside the scope of this site.

Thing is ... there's no Personal Productivity SE any more. It was shut down some months ago (for not being productive enough?), and that link only goes to a failed Area 51 proposal with a data dump.

- **Should Lifehacks reconsider the "mind hacks" close reason?** I know that scope overlaps with other sites aren't usually considered a good reason to change the scope of any one site, but if this close reason was created literally because PP.SE fit better, should it now be removed?
- **If not, then please at least change the wording of the close reason.** That essentially-dead link needs to go. There are two options here: either a mod, subject to approval by another mod, can deactivate the existing close reason and create a new one without referencing PP.SE; or a CM, at the request of mods, can edit the existing close reason to remove the PP.SE reference.

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm not an active user here; the only reason I have this much rep is one HNQ. I don't know the history behind this close reason or why it was created. Please excuse any faux pas in this meta post; they're inadvertent.</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally, we'd just replace the old reason with a new one.

But in this case that'd leave a bunch of broken links scattered around the site. So instead, I just trimmed down the text in situ:

> **"Mind hacks" are off topic** — Questions dealing with personal productivity and self-improvement tips, with memorization, learning techniques, etc. are outside the scope of this site.

This will apply to all past and future questions closed with that reason.

Comment: <grammar_pedant> *Questions dealing with personal productivity and self-improvement tips, `**or**` with memorization, learning techniques, etc.`**,**` are outside the scope of this site.* </grammar_pedant>

Comment: Could see if our lawyer has any all-caps to spare and add NOT WITHSTANDING somewhere...