# What stack exchange is suitable for "Mind hacks" including personal productivity & self-improvement tips, memorization & learning techniques, etc.?

Tags: discussion

### Background

On the [Tour](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/tour) page of this stack exchange, the following is listed as a reason to close a question:

> "Mind hacks" including personal productivity & self-improvement tips, memorization & learning techniques, etc.

I was itching to ask question almost exactly along these lines on a stack exchange, and Lifehacks.SE seemed to closest one to this. However, the fact that this is a specific close reason prompted me to ask the following question on the meta for Lifehacks.SE....

## Question

If I have a question relating to the quoted reason above, which stack exchange (or appropriate question answer forum site) will best address said reason [given that Productivity.SE is gone](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2711/the-mind-hacks-close-reason-after-the-death-of-productivity-se)?

Answer (score 3):

As it has been a couple years since [The "mind hacks" close reason after the death of Productivity SE](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2711/13) was posted, and as it specificaly asked about including mind hacks as in scope, and as no one has posted an answer suggesting it should now be in scope.

I think it is safe to assume, that there is no interest in having 'mind hacks' be inscope at lifehacks.se

Answer (score 1):

If you can’t find a good site covering the original topic *and* allowing this kind of mind hacks, then, sorry to say, the answer must be

> There is no place on the SE network where you can post your question.

I know this sucks and I’m sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but that’s how it is. The SE network has a huge range from very broad (Stack Overflow, 19 million questions, 11 million users) to small niches (Constructed Languages SE, 276 questions, 1.4k users). And still we don’t cover *everything*. A lot, but not everything.

Sometimes, the demise of one site can mean another will absorb some of the topics previously covered there, but that’s not the case for mind hacks on Lifehacks SE, according to the original site design<sup>1</sup> and there is no current community decision overriding this.

<sup>1</sup> See the [Lifehacks Manifesto](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/a-lifehacks-manifesto).

Answer (score -3):

I support making so called "mindhacks" in scope here again. I've seen a lot of great questions here that could have been in scope, if not for this rule.  Currently theirs no place to ask simple questions like:

- How do I remind myself to...
- How can I stay focused...
- How can I avoid the afternoon slump..
- and so forth...

As one of the sites to waste internet time on, maybe Stack Exchange could provide solutions as well. It would also benefit the site. Right now, Lifehacks SE only has [0.6 questions per day](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64409/lifehacks) on area 51. The last thing we need to be doing is ruling out a huge swath  of possible questions if we ever want this site to leave beta.

Comment: Re. the “leave beta” part: The current SE policy is (slightly paraphrased) that no site risks being closed just for being in Beta. The only criterion is the availability of reliable moderation - which looking back at the last election and judging by the flag handling time I observe definitely isn’t a problem here. Leaving Beta comes with drawbacks (just think about the higher privilege thresholds for community moderation and the ensuing problems) that has some sites explicitly wanting to stay in Beta. 0.7 questions isn’t a real problem, and a 3.7 answer ratio is excellent!

Comment: Btw, I *think* that you probably want to start a new question, not answer the existing one with a somewhat different scope? The question here is “where on the network can I post mind hacks, as they are off topic here?”, you are answering “Should mind hacks be on topic on Lifehacks SE?)